# Android: MetricAffectingSpan and RasterizerSpan

Tags: android, html

Can somebody please explain, how the following span-methods work (for a TextView) ?

If possible, please with a short example.

I have not found good explanations or examples in the web so far.

Many thanks in advance.

(a) MetricAffectingSpan
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/MetricAffectingSpan.html

(b) RasterizerSpan
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RasterizerSpan.html

Comment: Docs are just awful, shame on you, Google...